# How to find user-defined minimum and maximum value in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, max, tuples, minimum

I have a list of tuples with 2 integers each:

```
a_list=[(20, 1), (16, 0), (21, 0), (20, 0), (24, 0), (25, 1)]
```

What I am looking for is a way to find and return the tuple that has the smallest second item with the biggest first item. In the above list, it will be the tuple `(24, 0)`.

Comment: How does (25, 1) not have "the smallest second item with the biggest first item" in exactly the same way as (24, 0)?

Comment: Wait, I think I understand.  Do you mean that of those items with the lowest second item, you want the one with the biggest first item?

Comment: @Wooble: I meant first find the ones with the smallest second element, than among them, pick up the ones with largest first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> a_list = [(20, 1), (16, 0), (21, 0), (20, 0), (24, 0), (25, 1)]
>>> a = min(x[1] for x in a_list)
>>> max(b for b in a_list if b[1] == a)
(24, 0)
>>>
```

Comment: Is a "one-liner" an overkill?
`max(b for b in a_list if b[1] == min(x[1] for x in a_list))`

Comment: @AndyS.C. - You don't want a one-liner here.  Aside from being a tad unreadable, doing so will mean that it will recalculate  `min(x[1] for x in a_list)` with each iteration.  I made my answer two lines to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is trivial enough for the following approach to work

```
>>> a_list=[(20, 1), (16, 0), (21, 0), (20, 0), (24, 0), (25, 1)]
>>> max(a_list, key=lambda e:(-e[-1],e[0]))
(24, 0)
```

It assumes the fact that

1. Tuples are compared lexicographic-ally based on indexes

   See [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

   > Sequence types also support comparisons. In particular, tuples and
   >   lists are compared lexicographically by comparing corresponding
   >   elements. This means that to compare equal, every element must compare
   >   equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same
   >   length
2. Ordering of numbers revereses on change of sign

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that my understanding is correct, then here's what you need to do.

Find the minimum second value:

```
lowest = min(a_list, key=lambda t: t[1])[1]
```

Then find all the items that have that as the second item

```
having_lowest = filter(lambda t: t[1] == lowest, a_list)
```

Then find the one with the highest first number

```
having_max = max(having_lowest, key=lambda t: t[0])
```